# Can we extend this proof to show that arbitrary product of compact metric space is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

The above proves that the cartesian product of two compact metric spaces is compact, but can we use the same idea in the proof to extend it to an infinite product?

Comment: It's not so simple for arbitrary products, but it is true. See Tychonoff's theorem.

Comment: No., this proof works only for countable products.

Comment: Yes, I know tychonoffs theorem works for arbitrary topological spaces. Since we have restricted ourselves to only metric space, I thought it might be possible that there is an easier proof .

Comment: @Whatever proof there is, is based on Axiom of choice, so that already says that no straightforward extension of the finite dimensional case will be possible.

Comment: @William How do you define the metric on the infinite product?

Comment: @supinf For countable products there are standard ways to define a metric, for example $d=\sum2^{-j}\frac{d_j}{1+d_j}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Actually a proof for countably many metric spaces seems quite straightforward to me...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: agree, but the OP referred to arbitrary product spaces where the axiom of choice is required.